# Send AJAX request on each loop iteration after each AJAX success respond

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an array of ids, and I need to send each id with separate AJAX request. But each next id in the array needs to be sent only after AJAX received a success response from the server for the previuse request.

```
var idsArrays = [2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020 ];

    $.each(idsArrays, function( index, value ) {
        var data = "id="+value;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: formRequiredAction,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(resp){
                console.log('success ' + resp);
            },
            error: function(resp){
                console.log('error ' + resp);
            },
        });
    });
```

How can I set pause or wait time for next iteration until ajax will receive success response from the server?

Answer (score 0):

Just make your ajax sychronous and check with a variable if the call has succeeded. EDIT: Forgot it was an .each so break wont work. Just use return.

```
 $.each(idsArrays, function( index, value ) {
    var data = "id="+value;
    var success = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: formRequiredAction,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(resp){
            console.log('success ' + resp);
        },
        error: function(resp){
            console.log('error ' + resp);
            success = false;
        },
        async: false
    });
    if(!success){
       return false;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To chain all the ajax request without locking the browser with synchronous requests you can use promises.

In the example below I use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to digest the list one by one and get the reference of the previous promise. [`$.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) is used to create the first resolved promise to kick things off. `asyncAction()` is used to mirror an async operation.

```js
var idsArrays = [2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020 ];

idsArrays.reduce(function(lastPromise, id, index){
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  
  lastPromise.then(function(){
    asyncAction(id, deferred.resolve.bind(deferred))
  });  
  
  return deferred.promise();
}, $.when()).then(function(){
  console.log('All Done!');
});

function asyncAction(id, done){
  setTimeout(function(){    
      console.log('Sent', id);
      done();
  }, 250);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can replace `asyncAction()` with your ajax call, just make sure to resolve the promise calling `deferred.resolve()` within your ajax success callback. Do note that any failing ajax request will break the chain.

Comment: I'm getting a "deferred.resolve() is not a function" error after i replaced the function with my ajax call and placed the deferred.resolve() at the end of my success function. Any clues as to why?